# How to integrate a Script into ionic tab content?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'm starting to develop an application with the awesome ionic framework.

I've managed with your help of course to make a striped tabs which work perfectly. now i'm facing a problem with adding script to the ion-view content.

here is my tabs code : [my ionic tabs CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/stranger90/pen/MwjGPY)

and here is my page which I want to integrate as a tab content : [my tab content which i want to ingegrate CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/stranger90/pen/MwjXrp)

Can i do something like that ?

```
 <ion-view title="Home">
    <div ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<div class="list">
   <div ng-repeat="(competitionname, competition) in MatchesByCompetition">
       <div class="item item-divider" >
    {{ competition.name }}
  </div>  
      <a class="item" href="#" align="center" ng-repeat="matche in competition.matches" >
  <img ng-src="http://media-v4.i-dalgo3.com/Sport/Football/Team/Logo/55x55/logo_{{matche.team1.idTeam}}.png" style="width:28px; height:28px; position:absolute; left:10px; top:12px">      
  <h4 style=" display:inline-block; left:60px; position:absolute;"> {{matche.team1.name}}</h4> <h5 style=" display:inline-block;"> {{matche.newstartdate}}</h5>   <h4 style=" display:inline-block; position:absolute; right:60px; ">{{matche.team2.name}}</h4>  
  <img ng-src="http://media-v4.i-dalgo3.com/Sport/Football/Team/Logo/55x55/logo_{{matche.team2.idTeam}}.png" style="width:28px; height:28px; position:absolute; right:10px; top:12px" >      

  </a>   




    </div>

</div>

</div>



  </ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is, you can add another `tab`

`<ion-tab title="list" ui-sref="list">
  <ion-nav-view name="list"></ion-nav-view> 
</ion-tab>`

and instead of using inline scrips like `<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">` you can tell `ui-router` the to load an external page
in your router

`.state('list', {
  url: '/list',
  views: {
    list: {
      controler: 'customersCtrl',
      templateUrl: '<path to your file>list.html'
    }
  }
})`
 
and in fact its a good idea to move all your inline scripts to separate files

HTH